# How to discover protocols such as 'IntegerLiteralConvertible' in swift?

Tags: swift, protocols

So far this website http://swifter.natecook.com/ seems to be the best way to explore all the available protocols in the Swift language. But as [the creator's blog](http://natecook.com/blog/2014/09/introducing-swifter/) suggests, it is actually built by scrapping the swift language website.

My question is: is there any alternative way we can discover all these protocols created by the swift team from within the language or the IDE?

Comment: Opening the Swift header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Type out something in the standard library, like `IntegerLiteralConvertible` or `Equatable`, and command+click on it (or go to File → Open Quickly, type the same thing and open its definition file). This file, the Swift standard library header, contains all the functions, classes, structs, enums and protocols from the Swift standard library. Note that not everything is documented and that some things may be implementation details prone to change (as you might have seen if you've been following along the beta releases).

Comment: Did not know the 'Open Quickly' function before. Thanks!

Comment: Open Quickly is ridiculously handy, as is cmd+clicking.